# Do i need to upgrade react-scripts while upgrading from React 17 to React 18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-scripts, react-18

I have a react application using the `react` version `17.0.2` and `react-scripts` version `4.0.3`

I updated my react version to 18 but i didn't updated my react-scripts.

Is this a right approach? Do i really need to upgrade react-scripts as well to experience all the new features of React 18.

Comment: You can see the new features in v5 here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#500-2021-12-14. Note it was released _before_ React 18.